# cookie и поддомены

Tags: php, cookie, поддомены

Здравствуйте!
У меня такая проблема.
На главном домене domain.com создал куку:

```
setcookie ("webmID", $_GET['webmID'], time()+7*24*60*60, "/", ".domain.com");
```

На поддомене sub.domain.com данная кука выводится нормально, но вот удалить ее почему то не получается. Пробовал:

```
setcookie("webmID", "", time()-3600);
setcookie("webmID", "", time()-3600, "/");
setcookie("webmID", "", time()-3600, "domain.com");
unset($_COOKIE['webmID']);
```

Не получается удалить.
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Так пробовали?  

    setcookie ("webmID", "", 1, "/", ".domain.com");
Насчет `time()-3600` можно прочесть [здесь]( http://habrahabr.ru/post/146109/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```
setcookie ("webmID", "", time()-7*24*60*60, "/", ".domain.com");
```

И вообще лучше задавать куки вот так

```
setcookie ("webmID", $_GET['webmID'], time()+7*24*60*60, "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."любой поддомен");
```

Тогда при нескольких доменах сайта не будет ошибок.