# Как не терять авторизацию на сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт **mysite.ru** и **bla.mysite.ru** .
Сайт *bla.mysite.ru* - работает на поддомене, с той же базой данных что и сайт *mysite.ru* .

Когда пользователь проходит авторизацию на сайте **mysite.ru** - и после этого попадает на сайт **bla.mysite.ru** , авторизация пропадает.

При авторизации я записываю **id** юзера в `COOKIE` :

```
setcookie('id_us', $data['id'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/");
```

Каким образом можно сохранить авторизацию для сайта на поддомене?

Comment: пример решения тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166037/cookie-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: Это слегка оффтопик, но если для идентификации пользователя вы используете один только ID, вы в опасности. Ничего не стоит подделать такую куку и выдать себя за кого угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Полный список параметров setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) включает в себя домен. На обоих сайтах указывайте домен явно как ".mysite.ru" — точка впереди это не опечатка. Тогда у вас будут использоваться общие куки для обоих сайтов.

```
setcookie('id_us', $data['id'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/", ".mysite.ru");
```